# SharePoint 2013 hide elements (in body area ) when ribbon is expanded / ribbon is in use

Tags: javascript, css, ribbon, branding

Is there a css class/id in SharePoint 2013 that hide elements when the ribbon is in use?

I've got some elements that I don't want to show when the user's in edit mode!

In the picture below you can see that the ribbon is expanded (shown in red). IF the ribbon is expanded I want to hide the menu shown in blue cross. This is just an example!

[image]

To clarify what I mean with "ribbon is in use", that the ribbon is expanded (show picture marked as red):

[image]

Ex: the pagetitle  ( #s4-titlerow ) get's hidden .. ( .s4-titlerowhidetitle )

I know I can manage this with some javascript by checking the "active" ribbon tab. But isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "ribbon is in use"? Mouseover/click on button/click on ribbon tab?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know you asked for 2013 but I'm leaving the 2010 one here too in case anyone go crazy like you did.

**2010**

When any ribbon tab is open (other than the 'browse' one) it forces a 135px height on its container, which is a sibling of the `#s4-workspace` container, see where I am going?

```
#s4-ribbonrow[style='height: 135px;'] ~ #s4-workspace #s4-leftpanel {
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide the `#s4-leftpanel` only when the ribbon is stretched to the 135px height.

**2013**

Same deal but simpler, gladly we get an actual class in the #s4-titlerow container:

```
#s4-titlerow.s4-titlerowhidetitle ~ #contentRow #sideNavBox {
        display: none;
}
```

The general sibling selector `~` is IE7+ and the attribute selector IE8+ so even without testing it there it should do the trick on IE8+.

That was fun to put together, thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Finally I found something useful to use siblings on :)

Answer (score 3):

If the idea is that some content should "fall behind" the Ribbon (such as a header, navigation, etc.) you can just place your markup in the  with the ID "s4-titlerow".

This gets automatically hidden when the Ribbon displays, giving the effect that the Ribbon falls "on top" of the content.

Otherwise, I would give a try to any of the script proposed answers.

Answer (score 2):

this function:

```
function IsRibbonHidden()
{
return document.getElementById('RibbonContainer_activeTabId').value == "Ribbon.Read";
}
```

will return true when the ribbon is inactive, and false when it expanded (or null when the ribbon is absent). You can attach a javascript event receiver and hide/unhide the left menu depending on what the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to hide the `Edit Item` option. So, I identified the `id` for that tag and had  hidden it.

For `Edit Item` the `id` was `Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.EditProperties-Large` (you can easily check it from inspector tool in FireFox). And then doing `$("#Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.EditProperties-Large").hide()` worked.

Comment: I'm not trying to hide elements inside the ribbon, but in the body of the page! I wan't to do this without using jquery, if possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force this type of behaviour for users, then F.Aquino's solution is what you need.

Otherwise, there is one out-of-the-box solution for users: use the "Focus on Content" button on the top-right side of the ribbon.

[image: Focus on Content]